# I want to install ubuntu but will I be able to go back to windows?

Tags: windows

I have a new laptop and I want to install ubuntu on it, I would just like to know if there's any way I'll be able to go back to windows or run two operating systems at once.

Answer (score 0):

You may run two operating systems(dualbooting windows and ubuntu).

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Or

You can put back windows [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Install Windows and Ubuntu side-by-side using dual boot. Ubuntu will suggest you this on the installation Wizard.
- Install Ubuntu inside Windows using Wubi